# Equivalent of fwrite_unlocked on macOS?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, macos, fwrite

I have some code which runs on Linux and Windows which I'm currently porting to macOS. One sticking point is [`fwrite_unlocked`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite_unlocked) (Linux), which has an equivalent on Windows ([`_fwrite_nolock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eadhs8bd.aspx)), but not on macOS, as far as I can see. For now I'm just using `fwrite`, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution ? Will this just result in a performance hit, or am I risking more serious problems if I use `fwrite` for this ?

Comment: just out of curiosity, if you anyway use non standard functions, don't you prefer calling `WriteFile` and `write` directly?

Comment: @DavidHaim: I didn't write this part of the code - I'm just porting it to another platform - so I don't know the exact motivation behind the use of these calls.

Comment: It is odd seeing you ask a question. You usually have the answers, even to odd questions.

Comment: @jww: heh - none of us is omniscient!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From that man page, `fwrite_unlocked` is just like `fwrite` but less safe. So, there's no risk of "more serious problems" from using `fwrite`. It does seem likely that `fwrite` will be less performant; the whole purpose for the `_unlocked` functions is to be faster.

Note this from the man page:

> [The nonstandard *_unlocked() variants] should probably not be used.

Comment: Thanks - I think you're right - it looks like whoever wrote this code was just using the `fwrite_unlocked` calls to get better write performance, so there should not be a problem with falling back to plain old `fwrite` on macOS (other than a possible performance hit).

Comment: I'd also point out that the overhead of the lock in the standard `fwrite()` is almost certainly minuscule and probably entirely negligible when compared to the actual IO operation itself unless the code is doing something like calling `fwrite()` byte-by-byte to write a large amount of data.

Comment: @AndrewHenle So, what would you do if you actually do need to call `fwrite` often? Implement another layer of buffering around? Isn't that obsolete, as the file IO already has buffering internally?